# delete rows from xml data type with modify T-SQL 2008

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

I am trying to remove from the xml datatype field some rows. I have read many guides but unfortunately it looks i need a little push. It would be appreciated if someone can help me. Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @Xml TABLE (Data XML)
DECLARE @Data XML

set @Data=N'
<resultset>
    <row>
        <column name="PieceNo">1</column>
        <column name="PieceNoEvalUnit">655360</column>
        <column name="PieceIdent">Function check1</column>
        <column name="RequestNo">1</column>
    </row>
    <row>
        <column name="PieceNo">2</column>
        <column name="PieceNoEvalUnit">655362</column>
        <column name="PieceIdent">Function check2</column>
        <column name="RequestNo">1</column>
    </row>
    <row>
        <column name="PieceNo">3</column>
        <column name="PieceNoEvalUnit">655364</column>
        <column name="PieceIdent">Function check3</column>
        <column name="RequestNo">1</column>
    </row>
</resultset>'

INSERT  INTO @Xml( Data)
values(@data)

--update @xml set data.modify('
--delete (/resultset/row)[/column/text()[1]>="2"]
--')

--update @xml set data.modify('
--delete //row//column[text()][.PieceNo >= sql:variable("2")]
--')

select 
X.N.value('(column/text())[1]', 'int') as PieceNo,
X.N.value('(column/text())[2]', 'int') as PieceNoEvalUnit,
X.N.value('(column/text())[3]', 'varchar(255)') as PieceIdent,
X.N.value('(column/text())[4]', 'int') as RequestNo
from 
@Xml as T
cross apply t.Data.nodes(N'/resultset/row') as X(N)
```

Let's say for example that i want to delete from xml some rows when PieceNo>=2.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following command :

```
update @xml set data.modify('
    delete /resultset/row[column[@name="PieceNo"][.>=2]]
')
```

Above XPath means select `<row>` having child node `<column>` where `name` attribute value equals "PieceNo" and `<column>` node value more than or equals `2`.